# Is there any function to stop a function if user input is a pre-defined code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

here in #1 i want to make something like if name is code then start
developer function but after developers function is finished it may
complete the remaining part of the code but I dont want to Or I dont
want to print program finished Tell me something without using if
name!=code: Then all the remaining code I need to do if name!=code

````
def start():
    code = '1037'
    source = input('Your Name')
    if source==code:
        Pass #1
    else:
        start_nocode()#a pre defined fun not shown here```
    print('Program Finished')
````

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I understand English is not everyone's first language, but please take a bit of time to re-phrase the question, because currently it's almost incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of `return` here. It will stop your method right there and nothing below that in that method will be executed

```
def start():
    code = '1037'
    source = input('Your Name')
    if source==code:
        dev() # Not defined in this code
        return
    else:
        start_nocode()#a pre defined fun not shown here
    print('Program Finished')
```